Docker: "exec /bin/sh: exec format error" When Building arm64 Image on amd64 Jenkins
I'm encountering an "exec /bin/sh: exec format error" error while attempting to build an arm64 Docker image within a Jenkins CI/CD pipeline running on an amd64 platform.
Environment:

Jenkins docker plugin version (v1.5)
Target architecture (arm64)

Dockerfile:
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y upgrade \
  && apt-get install --yes \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    iproute2 \
    bash \
    sudo \
    coreutils \
    procps \
  && /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Installs python 3.8 and virtualenv for Spark and Notebooks
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    python3.8 \
    virtualenv \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Initialize the default environment that Spark and notebooks will use
RUN virtualenv -p python3.8 --system-site-packages /databricks/python3

Error Log:
17:07:42  #6 [2/9] RUN apt-get update    && apt-get -y upgrade    && apt-get install --yes    openjdk-8-jdk    iproute2    bash    sudo    coreutils    procps    && /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure    && apt-get clean    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

17:07:43  #6 0.459 exec /bin/sh: exec format error

17:07:43  #6 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update    && apt-get -y upgrade    && apt-get install --yes    openjdk-8-jdk    iproute2    bash    sudo    coreutils    procps    && /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure    && apt-get clean    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
17:07:43  ------
17:07:43  > [2/9] RUN apt-get update    && apt-get -y upgrade    && apt-get install --yes    openjdk-8-jdk    iproute2    bash    sudo    coreutils    procps    && /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure    && apt-get clean    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
17:07:43  0.459 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
Thanks

Context:
The build works successfully on both an arm64 local machine (Macbook M3) and an amd64 local machine (Ryzen 9).
Question:

How can I resolve the "exec /bin/sh: exec format error" when building an arm64 image on my Jenkins server (amd64 architecture)?
Is there a way to leverage the --platform flag in my Dockerfile to achieve arm64 builds within Jenkins without resorting to buildx?

Additional Information:
While I understand buildx might be a solution, I'd prefer to keep things simple and use the --platform flag if possible.
